# Is it possible to change the legend so the symbol is on the right side?

Tags: qgis, legend

Is it possible to change the legend arrangement so the symbol will be in right side and the label description will be in the left side? The QGIS default is label description in the right side and the symbol is in the left side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this currently - it has been under discussion by QGIS developers for a while. https://hub.qgis.org/issues/3239